# How to change color of a imageview that I load from Picasso from Green to Red

Tags: android, colors, imageview, picasso, tint

This is my code:

```
backPic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
backPic.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
Picasso.with(context).load(icon).into(backPic, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        UserVehicle.setVehicleClassPic(getVclass().getId(), backPic);
    }
});
```

The initial picture is this:

[image]

This is what I get now:

[image]

How can I make it so the bike in the second picture is red, not gray towards green?

The color I sent to the image filter is red.

Comment: You can use the `DrawableCompat.setTint()` to change your image color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the comment from André Sousa I did this code:

```
   Picasso.with(context).load(icon).into(backPic, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(backPic.getDrawable(), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    UserVehicle.setVehicleClassPic(getVclass().getId(), backPic);
                }
            });
```

So it would set the tint after the Picasso image has loaded, which works

Answer (score 0):

please read [here:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)

the problem is this line:

```
  backPic.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red), 
  android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

specifically:

```
  PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
```

you want:

```
 PorterDuff.Mode.DST
```

i believe. but if you read the docs i provided you will see what the different modes do. just remember when you math colors they do funny things. multiplying green and red is giving you that funky grey, the ADD mode would have been my first choice, but that will give you a funk brown. `DST` replaces the old pixel with the new ones, keeping it from mixing colors.

good luck!

Comment: DST returns the green image, not red. I am now looking into all modes, and will try them to see which one works best for me